# Javascript Store Opening Hours

Tags: javascript

Basically I want to create Open Hours for Store.

The Store has open hours from 12:00 to 15:00 and from 17:00 to 22:00.
I made it to display current time on the modal page where the "Enter" button is to show the current time, but I wish that during the non working hours the button to enter the site gets removed so that users can't enter the webpage.

I also would like to see how to change it depending on day, for example if Tuesday has open hours from 11:00 - 15:00 and 17:00 - 23:00.

I use openStatus.js

So far this is my code:

```
var d = new Date();
var n = d.getDay()
var h = d.getHours();

if (n == 1) {

 if (h >= 22 && h < 12) {
    $(".enter-button").remove();
  }
 if (h > 15 && h <= 17)
   $(".enter-button").remove();
} 
else {
   $(".enter-button").css("display", "block");
}
```

Maybe I should get the hours from 0 - 24 in an array an assign open hours to variables and do that approach?
Thank you, as I am still learning these things.

Comment: Does this code not work the way you expect?

Comment: Your first condition will never execute.  `h` can't be both greater than or equal to 22 and less than 12.

Comment: `h >= 22 && h < 12` What number is greater than 22 and less than 12?

Comment: @EatPeanutButter for example if i make "if h = 15" and it is 15, the button gets removed. However, when I am adding the "&&" it doesn't work at all.

Comment: Bear in mind, that visitors may be in the different time zone, which means you need to adjust for that.

Comment: @EvanTrimboli well, if "current hour" is 23, it should remove the button. If the current number passes 00, say it's 1 in the morning, shouldn't it be "< 12" then?

Comment: Right, but the code doesn't reflect that. A number can't be > 22 AND < 12. You probably mean OR.

Comment: @EvanTrimboli http://codepen.io/aortaFX/pen/YqJypx I think this might work :D

Comment: Consider one line `if ((h >= 22 || h < 12) || (h > 15 && h <= 17)) {$(".enter-button").remove();}`

Comment: Whether the store is open or closed, based on day/hour or _any_ other condition, should be determined _on the **server**_, not in javascript on the _client_.  The client timezone, as @dark_ruby mentions, is an issue, but it is also vulnerable to client manipulation.  The store is open when ***I*** say it's open, because I can tinker with the JS that runs in the browser.

Comment: @StephenP It will be for local food delivery, so timezone isn't a issue here. "Hacking" the site (or even removing the modal) isn't a concern, as the order won't be fullfiled anyways.

Comment: @xerox - a friend was taking over a "local" restaurant website and asked for some advice. Local for him, over 1,000 miles away from me.  I saw it was vulnerable to tampering. I ordered some food and got a $1.00 _credit_ on my Visa (which I gave back) and didn't care that I'd never get the food. Lesson: hacking is _always_ a concern.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at this.

It's a bit rough, bit it should work. I haven't used openStatus.js

**This does not take into consideration Time zones.**

```
    <script>

    var d = new Date();
    var n = d.getDay();
    var now = d.getHours() + "." + d.getMinutes();
    var weekdays = [
        ["Sunday", 9.30, 12.00, 15.30,22.00],
        ["Monday", 8.30, 12.00, 15.30,19.00],
        ["Tuesday", 8.30, 12.00, 15.30,19.00],
        ["Wednesday", 8.30, 12.00, 15.30,19.00],
        ["Thursday", 8.30, 12.00, 15.30,19.00],
        ["Friday", 8.30, 11.30],
        ["Saturday"] // we are closed, sorry!
    ];
    var day = weekdays[n];


    if (now > day[1] && now < day[2] || now > day[3] && now < day[4]) {
        console.log("We're open right now!");
    }
     else {
        console.log("Sorry, we're closed!");
    }


</script>
```

Comment: This is awesome man! Thanks

Comment: Yes, but remember to set time zones. A better solution would be server side.

Comment: It is really for a local store (food delivery) so it won't really matter I think. But could be nice exercise for future work. Thanks again.

Comment: @Enrico this is really good but now variable is string when concatenated. Use maybe simple  `var now = (d.getHours() + "." + d.getMinutes())*1;` to make it a number.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that this is what you are looking for, move the `else` into the first `if`, see fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/c259LrpL/5/

I replaced `h` and `n` to hard coded values for testing

```
<input type="button" value="enter button" class="enter-button">
<script>
  var n = 1;
  var h = 13;

  if (n == 1) {

    if (h >= 22 || h < 12) {
      $(".enter-button").remove();
    }
    else if (h > 15 && h <= 17){
      $(".enter-button").remove();
    }
    else { //Move your else inside the first if()
      $(".enter-button").css("display", "block");
    }
  }

</script>
```

Comment: This might work. I will try it out. Thank you man!