# How make this javascript work with business opening hours over midnight?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, datetime, time

I use the following javascript to see if the business is open based on the business hours. it is simple and works great but how can I make this work with hours past midnight like 0:30 or 1:00 in the morning. Unfortunatly it works only for times like 17:00-23:00 but not for 17:00-030:

```
var d = new Date();
var n = d.getDay();
var now = d.getHours() + "." + d.getMinutes();
var weekdays = [
    ["Sunday", 9.30, 12.00, 15.30,22.00],
    ["Monday", 8.30, 12.00, 15.30,19.00],
    ["Tuesday", 8.30, 12.00, 15.30,19.00],
    ["Wednesday", 8.30, 12.00, 15.30,19.00],
    ["Thursday", 8.30, 12.00, 15.30,19.00],
    ["Friday", 8.30, 11.30],
    ["Saturday"] // we are closed, sorry!
];
var day = weekdays[n];


if (now > day[1] && now < day[2] || now > day[3] && now < day[4]) {
    console.log("We're open right now!");
}
 else {
    console.log("Sorry, we're closed!");
}
```

I know this script don't support timezones but this isn't important to my since this is only for local business which are always in the same timezone as the clients.

thanks in advance.
PS: the original script is from another post here in stackoverflow [Javascript Store Opening Hours](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36900482/javascript-store-opening-hours)

**UPDATED VERSION** I changed the script because I use json data from firebase and get already the times for the day so I dont need the array with the days.

```
<script>

    var d = new Date();
    var n = d.getDay();
    var now = d.getHours() + "." + d.getMinutes();

    // this is what I get from firebase already 
    // so I dont need to loop throught the days but throught the 2 different opening times.
    var day = {
    "from": 8.30,
    "to": 10,
    "from2": 14.30,
    "to2": 23    
    };

console.log('Now: ' + now);

    if (now > day.from && now < day.to || now > day.from2 && now < day.to2) {
        console.log("We're open right now!");
    } else {
        console.log("Sorry, we're closed!");
    }

</script>
```

How ever this is not working if I have things like 17:00-01:00.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After testing around I found a way by myself. I ended up creating a small function. You can send the open and closed times to the function and get a reply if the business is open or closed. Works with all times and also over midnight.

How ever, this script does not work for business in other timezones since it does not take care for any location based times. If you use for a local business where the clients are in the same timezone as the business works fine.

```
   // Example with JSON data for the current day.
    var day = {
    "from": 17.30,
    "to": 1.30
    };

var check_now = check_business_status(day.from, day.to);
console.log('The bussines is ' + check_now);

function check_business_status(from, to) {

    var d = new Date();
    var n = d.getDay();
    var now = d.getHours() + "." + d.getMinutes();

console.log('Now: ' + now);
console.log(from + ' // ' + to);

// First check if to date is smaller than from date and their for tomorrow!
if (from > to){
console.info('Closing time is after midnight! Special Check...');

    var status = '';
    if (now < to && from > now) {
        status = "open";
    } else if (now > to && from > now) {
        status = "closed";
    } else if (now > to && from < now && now > from) {
       status = "open";
    }

} else {
console.info('Closing time is before midnight! Normal Check...');
    if (now > from && now < to) {
        status = "open";
    } else {
        status = "closed";
    }
}
 return status;
}
```

You can also test with different times in jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/oliver2000/4pdogett/1/

Answer (score 0):

You can work with Local time or work with a date library like http://www.datejs.com/  or https://momentjs.com/

Parse `(new Date).toLocaleString()` and work with your data based on this date-time.

```
var date = new Date();
var formatted = date.toLocaleString('de-DE');
```

To get the timezone you can use `navigator.language`

Comment: Thx for your reply. I have bad experience with momentjs because the results on ios are different as they are on android or browser for me. I want to avoid using additional javascript like momentjs or timezone etc. for that reasons. I also want to keep it as simple as possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this.

```
var d = new Date();
var n = d.getDay();
var now = d.getHours() + "." + d.getMinutes();
var weekdays = [
    ["Sunday", 9.30, 12.00, 15.30,2.00],
    ["Monday", 8.00, 12.00, 15.30,19.00],
    ["Tuesday", 8.30, 12.00, 15.30,19.00],
    ["Wednesday", 8.30, 12.00, 15.30,19.00],
    ["Thursday", 8.30, 12.00, 15.30,19.00],
    ["Friday", 8.30, 11.30],
    ["Saturday"] // we are closed, sorry!
];
var day = weekdays[n];


if (now < day[1] && now > day[2] || now < day[3] && now > day[4]) {
      console.log("Sorry, we're closed!");
}
 else {
   if(n != 0){
     day = weekdays[n-1];
   }
   else{
     day = 6;
   }

   if ((now > day[4])) {
     console.log("Sorry, we're closed!");
  }
   else {
     console.log("We're open right now!");
  }
}
```

Comment: Your version still does not work with times like 17:30 - 01:00. If you change for example ["Sunday", 9.30, 12.00, 15.30,1.00] and test the result is "closed!". I did adapt the script above already a little bit because I get from firebase already the times for the current day as json. thx for your help.

Comment: So if you have a fixed file format you can use another if else statement to check the current time with the closing hours from the day before

Comment: I am not sure if I understand your example, it isn't working for me in my tests either. Maybe I explained wrong. I setup a fiddle to show you exactly what I have so far https://jsfiddle.net/oliver2000/4pdogett/1/ I get the opening times as json for the current day. all works as long as the day.to or day.to2 times are at the same day but does fail if the closing time is after midnight (next day). so if I edit my script to day.to2 to something like 1.30 it fails. as long as I use 23:59 it works. Maybe you can use my fiddle. thx for your time and help.@leo

Comment: Sorry, my answer was not very good it was to late. 
But the intetion was to check if the shop is open today and if not, check on the previous day if it is open after 24.00. The problem you have is that 0.30 is not the correkt day anymore it is the next day. Thats the reason why I used the exampel with the array with more elements. But if you have this specific type of data you have to make a few if cases to catch all possible cases.